# What is the difference between the meanings of "afterwards" and "then"

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, differences, synonyms

We can use "Then" at the beginning of a sentence.
Meanwhile, we can put "Afterwards," at the start of a sentence.
What is the difference between such two usages' meanings?

I am not sure does "Afterwards," stands for a longer pause compared to "Then". Or is "Afterwards" more formal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Then* simply means *the next thing that happened was...* They could be quite routine things.

"I got up, then had breakfast, then took the dog for a walk."

We would use *afterwards* to refer to something that happened *after* a significant action or event.

"I spent the afternoon working hard in my garden. Afterwards, I was too tired to do anything but relax in front of the TV."

Answer (score -1):

As a conjunction or preposition use *after*. In this sense, it means ‘later than’ and ‘next in time or place’.

The problem comes when you need to use them as an adverb. After is not usually used alone. It is usually part of an adverbial phrase.

"Shall we have a swim after lunch?"

"The bank is just after the park, on the left."

These two examples were taken from [Cambridge grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/after-afterwards).

A good rule of thumb would be that afterwards can be usually substituted by "after that".

"I’m going to do my exams, and afterwards I'm going to study medicine."

This last example was taken from [Practical English Usage](https://elt.oup.com/catalogue/items/global/grammar_vocabulary/practical_english_usage_4th_edition/?cc=global&selLanguage=en).